# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: not queuing selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

I've setup a block to run on a different queue and call another method after a delay:

```
piemanQ = dispatch_queue_create(PIEMAN_QUEUE_NAME, NULL);
dispatch_async(piemanQ, ^{
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendReadyToPieman) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
});
```

I expect that a second later the `@selector(sendReadyToPieman)` fires, however nothing happens. I've read through the doco on the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and it talks about the method being added via a timer on the current queue. I've checked the current queues run loop mode, but it returns nil.

I'm sure I've done this sort of code before, but I've tried this in two different places and in both cases it has not run. But if I replace it with a `dispatch_after(...)` everything works.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the operation on an NSOperationQueue instead:

```
NSOperationQueue *piemanQ = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
piemanQ.name = @"some name";
[piemanQ addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendReadyToPieman) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}];
```

This is automatically asynchronous. It is better to use an Objective-C solution over a C solution to a problem.

Comment: An awesome suggestion. I've not used NSOperation queues as yet, but I suspect that swapping over to them will stream line some other code I have. I'll have to give this a try and see what happens.

Comment: Your code will look a lot nicer than with all these C methods around :)

Comment: I agree with everything you say here. But, alas, it doesn't answer the original question. This `NSOperationQueue` rendition will suffer from precisely the same problem as the code in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is: dispatch_async does what it says, it makes the following stuff run async. You queue your selector, then the block is finished and the whole async thing goes away. Including the queued selector, of course.

For the performSelector to do anything, the thread needs to be alive, and it needs to execute the runloop.

Comment: That makes sense, but my reading says that performSelector adds a NSTimer to the queue which fires after the delay to execute the selector. The GCD info I've read says that queues do not shutdown until everything queued to them has executed. So theoretically by executing performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: should queue up another NSTimer on the queue and therefore stop it shutting own. At least that's what I understand from the doco. But it doesn't seem to work. Replacing it with an explicit dispatch_Async does work.